# three.js load multiple objects asynchronous issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, three.js

am loading multiple models on the same time to a scene, but it fails to load all the models, it only loading one model on the scene

For example am having a building scene with the multiple objects like chairs, toys and so on inside that building, while loading those objects the only one object is loading, but somehow if i do a alert on end of the function all the models are loading

[image: Example 1 what am getting now]

[image: Example 2 what i want]

Image1 what am getting now, Image2 what actually i want

my code is follows

```
function load_file(floor_number,x,y,z,width,height,rotation,angle,file)
{       
obj_x=x;
obj_y=y;
obj_z=z;
obj_width=width;
obj_height=height;
obj_rotation=rotation;
var object_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({                 
          color: 0xd6d6d6,  
          traansparent : true,
          opacity   : -2.5,
          side: THREE.DoubleSide            
      });       
var   loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();      
loader.load("uploads/accessories/3d/code/3dfile_"+file+".js",
          function(geometry, object_material) 
          {

              var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(object_material));
              console.log(object);
              model = new THREE.Object3D();

              model.add(object);    
              model.position.set(obj_x,obj_y,obj_z);        
              model.scale.set(obj_width,obj_height,obj_rotation);   
              model.opacity =2;
              model.rotation.y = 600; 
              model.duration = 12000;
              model.mirroredLoop = true;
              model.castShadow = true;
              model.receiveShadow = true;
              scene.add(model);                         
          }
      );        

     // alert('hi'); if i remove this comment second model is loading perfectly
return true;                    
}
```

also tried to load the object's by id using `Object3D.getObjectById()` this is also fails
i know this is about the asynchronous problem, but i can't get ride of this, any help on this?

Comment: Why are all (most) of your variables global?

Comment: yes because am getting geometry and materials from other loops,this is my code only to add the model to the scene, can you understand my situation ?

Comment: Could you maybe show us these loops? Global variables hardly ever make sense. Where are all these `obj_*` variables declared?

Comment: Hi @Bergi you can check the full code here http://pastebin.com/4QWymQ79

Comment: Sounds like the [classic closure in loop scope problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572). However, that code is too long and convoluted to tell for sure.

Comment: Hi @Bergi can you help me? to fix it

Comment: No, as I said I don't know your code and won't read into it. You know your code, so: Was my guess correct and is it a scope issue?

Comment: Does `console.log(object);` works for you inside loader callback?

Comment: "model = new THREE.Object3D();" why do you create a extra 3DObject? model = object. .... or just use object all along until you get to the line scene.add(object).

Comment: Hi @Benedikt i need all the models on the different places,so i used `model = new THREE.Object3D();` to create the temporary model and after add it into the scene i `used scene.add(model);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the globals.

Here a nice reading about [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

**update**

I played around a bit with a code similar to your, and I see now what could be what it seem a problem, but it isn't really, you can use an approach like this:

```
/* object declaration and initialization on load completed */
var model1;
load_file('object1', function(model) {
   model1 = model;
   model1.position.x = -2;
});
... 
function laad_file(file, on_load_complete) {
   ...
   loader.load("http://localhost/"+file+".js",  function(geometry, object_material)  {
      ...
      scene.add(model);
      /* call the callback to initialize your object */
      if (on_load_complete !== undefined)
         on_load_complete(model);
   });
   ...
}

render() {
   ...
   if (model1 !== undefined) 
      model1.rotation.x += 0.1;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alex i tried all the methods and none of them are not working to me,

Comment: Hi @JothiKannan forget about the *old answer*, I think the problem is that you re-use the global variable `model` for every `add.scene`, but when you create and assign a `new THREE.Object3d` to `model`, you're **destroying** the old one already assigned (it become garbage for the garbage collector), let me know if isn't clear, I can try to set up a simple test.

Comment: am not familiar with js,so can you show me a example ?

Comment: Ok let me some time, I'll let you know here.

Comment: @JothiKannan seem re-using the global isn't an issue at least with three.js version r68 (are you using same version?) [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x660fxcg/), may you put your json model .js online somewhere so I can test the load_file?

Comment: @JothiKannan or copy it to pastebin I'll use a local server.

Comment: @JothiKannan I tried with a simple cube from blender in the while, re-created your situation, **the problem are the globals** (obj_x & family), the object is loaded two times but with same position, take a look to here http://pastebin.com/RXSU9X3f in particular near `comment this` and `uncomment this`

Comment: yes @Alex i found it by today morning, but i doesn't get right direction to move further, what is your suggestion here ?

Comment: @JothiKannan you should really review your code to avoid globals. I didn't took a look to your full code, isn't clear to me why you need variables like `obj_x`, if a model's `x` is needed from a function add an argument `myobject` then use `myobject.x`

Comment: thanks man, really appreciate your effort on this, finally it worked if i use `model.position.set(x,y,z);` this :)))

Comment: You're welcome. I know it work but you'll end up with some inconsistency if you continue to use `obj_x` in other functions. Warned ;) have fun

Comment: am reading your link, and may i know how my global `obj_x` is evil on here, bcoz i doesn't used this `obj_x` anywhere on code except `obj_x=x` here, just give me hint that would be useful to me in the future

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your problem is that renderer not firing after model added to the scene. Try to call it after model added to the scene at your callback function:

```
scene.add(model); 
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @antyrat , but it doesn't make any sense on the result, still am getting the same result

Comment: yes on the console am getting like  `Object { id=41, uuid="B11412C6-2A91-4F47-9133-AE476B25A087", parent={...}, more...}
3d_tool...proid=3 (line 801)
Object { id=43, uuid="8453B8A7-1193-454E-B91F-5462BDEC0CA1", parent={...}, more...}
3d_tool...proid=3 (line 801)`

Comment: @JothiKannan and can you show how do you call `load_file` and where?

Comment: hi @antyrat my full code is here http://pastebin.com/NNUByWGP, can you look at here?

Comment: Hi @JothiKannan I'm looking on it, don't worry, I will try to help you ;)

Comment: Hi @antyrat got any solution for this issue?